# How to pass spring model attributes as a parameter on a HTML element utilizing a JS function

Tags: html, spring, postgresql, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a very simple CRUD operation program and I am having extreme difficulties passing an ID value of a model that I created. I am thinking that the error may be thymeleaf issue because I am not very well educated on that aspect.

I am simply trying to link a javascript function onto a button that passes an ID as the parameter so that it can find that user and delete or edit that user but the syntax is telling me that I am missing commas or brackets no matter what I try.

```
<div th:each="user:${us}" class="student-bubble" draggable="true" >
            <div th:text="${user.name}" class="student-name"></div>
            <div th:text="${user.email}"class="student-info"></div>
            <div th:text="${user.gpa}" class="student-info"></div>
            <div th:text="${user.height}" class="student-info"></div>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="edit-button"  onclick= "editUser(event, ${user.uid})">Edit</button>
                <button class="delete-button" onclick= "deleteUser(${user.uid})">Delete</button>
            </div>
            
</div>
```

I have tried concatenating the string and also back ticks, I have also tried using single and double quotations and no luck.

Comment: I can provide the js function alongside my controller file as well

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf is only processed on attributes if they are prefixed with `th:`.  Since you have `onclick` and not `th:onclick` your JavaScript is trying to run the code `editUser(event, ${user.uid})` which isn't valid JavaScript -- you can easily verify this by running your app and viewing your HTML source in the browser.

While that explains the invalid syntax, the correct way to do this is still to use onclick -- something like this:

```
<button class="edit-button" onclick="editUser(event, this.getAttribute('data-id'))" th:data-id="${user.uid}">Edit</button>
```

Comment: I get an error message There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/users/main.html]")

Comment: I tested my code it locally on Spring Boot and it works for me -- the error message you posted doesn't really say anything.  The actual error is somewhere in your logs.